# Is getting host IP address (requester) from HTTP request message possible?

Tags: network

On an HTTP request message, there is a field for the host ip address and the url of the server : GET **/cs453/index.html** ~ Host: **gaia.cs.umass.edu**

But How about the IP address of host (requester, where the browser that is sending this request message is running)?

I think a server needs to know the client's host from HTTP request message, but there is no field for that.

How does it work?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the concept of the different layers in networking.

HTTP is an application layer protocol. When an HTTP message gets sent, it uses TCP as the transport layer protocol.

TCP chops the HTTP message into segments and adds a TCP header to each segment. The TCP header includes the source and destination port numbers (TCP addresses). TCP then uses IP to deliver the TCP segments.

IP takes the TCP segments and encapsulates them into IP packets. The IP packets have IP headers which contain the source and destination IP addresses. IP uses a layer-2 protocol, such as ethernet to deliver the IP packets.

Ethernet encapsulates the IP packets into ethernet frames. Each ethernet frame has an ethernet header which contains the source and destination MAC addresses. Ethernet then sends the ethernet frames, which contain the IP packets, which contain the TCP segments, which contain the pieces of the HTTP message, to the hardware which sends the bits out.

As the application message travels down the stack, the data get encapsulated at each of the various layers, and each layer has it own address scheme which is used in the header of the datagram for that layer.

When the server receives the bits, it reverses the process until the HTTP request is delivered to the HTTP server. When the HTTP server replies, it uses the same process to encapsulate and send the reply back to the PC.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr: the true client's source IP address is usually known via the IP packet delivered to the web server.**

However, in the case of source NAT (sNAT) or HTTP proxies between client and server, the true client IP will not be in the packet the server sees.  The x-forwarded-for (XFF) header should contain the client's real IP when HTTP intermediaries are involved as the IP seen by the web server is the proxy's IP.  With sNAT, true client IP is lost unless the device doing the sNAT creates/rewrites a HTTP header like XFF discussed earlier or another custom header to contain it.